# What is repository latency and how can I troubleshoot it?

Tags: search

On my search service application on a dev environment I have a repository latency between 3000ms to 10000ms which is way too high.

Is this the latency to one specific database? which one is it?

How can I troubleshoot this latency problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219611%28v=office.15%29.aspx#proc2):

[image]

Under Crawl health reports > Crawl Report > **Crawl Latency**:

> For a specified time interval, also shows a graph and a summary of the
>   crawl latency; the amount of time in milliseconds that each content
>   item is in each of the following subsystems in the feeding pipeline:
>
> - Crawler
> - Protocol handler (PH)
> - Repository
> - SQL Time

They are actually missing one which is content processing (CTS).

**[This SP 2013 search troubleshooting article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristopherloranger/archive/2013/05/30/sharepoint-2013-crawler-troubleshooting-concepts.aspx)** mentions:

> New additions to the Crawler History view are the Crawl rate (DPS) and Repository Latency (MS) .
>   Previously, the administrator had to go to the crawl health reports to see this info for a particular content source.
>
> - Crawl Rate details the docs per second per crawl session.
> - Repository Latency details latency times in milliseconds during continuous crawl sessions.

I'm no expert, but what I would take from this is that "repository" latency indicates the time it takes the database to return the content from the moment it's requested. The databases are the data sources as is indicated [in the diagram below](http://www.searchtechnologies.com/sharepoint-15-search-overview.html), showing the SP 2013 search pipeline:

[image]

Comment: wonderful!!!!!!!

Comment: What is SQL time used for?